# How to run WCF web service and multithread task inside windows service separately?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, task-parallel-library, task

I have windows service and WCF web service hosted inside. Infinite task needs to read some logs from device every 2 seconds. In same time web service methods should work properly when they are called. In my case, when i Debug it seems that web service methods calls interrupts Infinite task. So my task is not running on different thread.

How can I optimize my code to work separately from WCF web service? Where is the problem?

On windows service start

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args){
 //....other code for starting WCF web service....
 work();
}
```

work method:

```
public async void Work() {

    log.Debug("operation started");
    Methods checkE = new Methods();
    try
    {         
        await checkE.PullLogs();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {

        log.Error(ex.Message);
    }

}
```

This is PullLogs method:

```
public async Task PullLogs ()
{
    while (true)
    {
       ... some code ...
                Parallel.ForEach(tasks, task =>
                {
                    byte[] dataArrayPC;
                    byte[] dataArrayCT;
                    byte[] rezult;
                    PTest p = new PTest();
                    if (p.PingIt(task.Ip))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            SDKCommunication con = new SDKCommunication(task.Id, task.Ip, port, timeout, false);                                                                         
                                ...some code...
                                       while (indexPC <= indexCT )                                                                                              
                                        {                                                                                                    
                                            int broj = con.ReadLogs(address, LOGS, indexPC, 16, 0); 
                                            rezult = con.GetLogs(broj);
                                            readEventData(rezult);
                                            indexPC = indexPC + 16;
                                            if (maxiterrations > itteration) {
                                                //send to Java web service
                                            }
                                            itteration++;
                                        }
                                con.Dispose();

                            else { log.Debug("error in sdk"); con.Dispose(); }

                        }
                        catch (Exception e) { log.Debug(e.Message); }
                    }
                    else { log.Error("no connection to device: " + task.Ip); }                        
                }
              );                       
        await Task.Delay(2000);
    }      
}
```

**EDIT:**
One more question, is it better to use while(true) and Task.Delay(2000) or have timer tick for every 2 seconds?
Thanks

Comment: per your edit, timer ticks are usually the preferred way for me, but it is kind of a opinion/coding style question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you are seeing what you think you are seeing. It sounds like you observed with the debugger that WCF service call interrupted your `PullLogs` code ... but perhaps the code was executing concurrently on different threads, and the debugger just switched you from one to another when a breakpoint was hit or something similar.

In general your WCF service method calls should be executing on the IO Completion Thread Pool. Your TPL code in the `Parallel.ForEach` should be executing with the default TaskScheduler on the default Thread Pool.

See here for more on specifying your own sychronization context (which will determine which threads WCF code can execute on):

[Synchronization Contexts in WCF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163321.aspx)

If your goal is to make sure that no WCF service calls are processed while your `PullLogs` code is running, then you will need a synchronization approach, like locking on the same object from the WCF methods, and also from the `PullLogs` code.

If instead your goal is to make sure that these two parts of your code are isolated, so that both are available to run simultaneously, then I don't think you need to do anything.

Now if you have observed that while your `PullLogs` code is executing, the WCF service is not as available as you want it to be, then I would take this to indicate that some resource (hardware threads, who knows) is being oversubscribed by the parallel loop in your `PullLogs` method. In that case probably the best you would be able to do is to naively limit concurrency in that loop to some smaller value ... which might slow down your `PullLogs` method, but could also go a long way towards making sure your WCF service remains available.

If you want to give this a try, you can create a LimitedConcurrencyTaskScheduler as is done here:

[How to: Create a Task Scheduler That Limits Concurrency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351(v=vs.110).aspx)

and then in your code, supply an instance of this task scheduler to your call to `Parallel.ForEach`.

Again I don't think this should be necessary unless you have noticed an actual problem (so far you only indicate that you noticed some behavior in the debugger that you didn't expect, but that sounds perfectly reasonable to me).

Comment: I think you tell something wrong... For "code to never run on the same threads" [...] "you should have one or both of them not operating on the threadpool" ... A thread pool is a pool of thread. This means inside a ThreadPool, there are multiple threads. So you can run multiples parts of code on different threads inside the same thread pool without problems...

Comment: @Sharped what you say is true, but it does not contradict my statement. The OP was concerned that two parts of his code were executing on the same thread, my statement is that the only way to prevent this from ever happening, is to separate one of them from the threadpool. Otherwise there will always be a chance that the two parts will end up running on the same thread (not at the same time obviously).

Comment: @TCC - my PullLogs is stopped while WCF web service methods are executing. That's the problem!

Comment: @user1598696 perhaps if you indicate more about your observation it will help ... for instance you have a long-running WCF method (what is it doing?) and you observe that pulllogs doesn't run during this time (how do you observe this?) ... to be sure i have many windows services with self hosted WCF services and looping asynchronous code similar to what you have and do not have this problem. More detail is needed on your observations ... there is a possibility that the method of observation is contributing to the problem for instance (like if you are breaking in the debugger for testing).

Comment: @TCC - WCF method is not long-running. Methods reads date from device. WCF methods generally use the same SDK as PullLogs, but for different short-time tasks. When i debug WCF method my PullLogs method is not running at all, it is blocked, waiting for WCF method to finish.